# Azure Functions - Event Hub Trigger - Beta Version /V2

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, eventtrigger

I'm trying to use the beta version/V.2 (I'm using the Microsoft Graph API) of the Azure Functions creating an Event Hub Trigger for an IoT device. However, I get an error just installing the extensions. "Extensions not Installed - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs".

We were not able to install the runtime extension. To learn more please view https://functionsmeetingroom.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/data/Functions/extensions/f5728d04-0b6c-4514-a780-43d6faddc4fd.json

Why? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an explicit entry to your .csproj file.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="3.0.0-beta5" />
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Hi Preeti, 
Many thanks for your reply.
It doesn't allow me to create the event if I don't go through the package installation but I get an error doing that,

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.
I followed also this link: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1558


and I get the following error:
D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.1.302\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Access to the path 'D:\home.nuget\system.net.websockets\4.0.0' is denied. [D:\home\site\wwwroot\HubTriggerMeetingRoom\extensions.csproj]
    1 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Comment: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="3.0.0-beta5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.0-beta7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.2.1-beta3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.MicrosoftGraph" Version="1.0.0-beta3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.*" Version="3.0.0-beta5" />

Answer (score 0):

Extension installation via portal is not very consistent. Your app is can get into a bad state without much effort. To fix it you could follow the steps mentioned here.

https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/94#issuecomment-376647094

**Update extensions.csproj with latest version of the nuget package, look up nuget.org for the latest version of extensions**

- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.MicrosoftGraph
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.* (Everything Else)

**Follow these steps to fix a function app written in the portal:**

- Stop the function app.
- Access kudu console through Platform Features -> Advanced Tools -> Debug Console (cmd)
- Navigate to d:\home\site\wwwroot
- Delete the bin directory
- Edit extensions.csproj
- Update with the appropriate versions (see above)
- Run dotnet build extensions.csproj -o bin --no-incremental --packages D:\home.nuget
- Start the function app